# How can I switch the footer's position with the paginator position

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

Because of some personal needs I need to switch the position of the footer with the paginator for my PrimeFaces DataTable:

Current:

[image]

How it should be:

[image]

Is it possible to do this without CSS? Is there a way to change the position programmatically? I think if this is possible it would be the best way to do this.

Comment: Simply changing the markup is not an option?

Comment: I'm using the DataTable component in PrimeFaces. I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to edit the CSS because if the position is relative for example this won't necessarily work. However simply arranging the position in HTML will change the order if the elements are at the default CSS values.

```
<div class="footer">Test</div>
<div class="pagination">1</div>
```

instead of:

```
<div class="pagination">1</div>
<div class="footer">Test</div>
```

Comment: I'm using the DataTable component in PrimeFaces. I don't know if this is possible.